# req-flash session issues using express within docker container

Tags: node.js, express, docker

I have an express app, with which I'm using redis for sessions. I'm using the latest redis Docker image and connect it to an isolated docker bridge network.

I'm having issues (Error shown below) with req-flash if I build a Docker image of the app and launch it (connecting it to the same bridge network as the redis server and expose it's ports to the host).

If I exec into the app container, I can connect fine to the Redis container using the bridged network.

The host 'redis-cache' is the name of redis container.

The app runs as intended if I don't use Docker for the app, but still use the redis container.

I've also had the same issues with docker-compose.

I'm using vagrant for the host, with box ubuntu/trusty64.
The version of node is 4.4.3 (host and docker image).
The version of Docker is 1.11.1.

Dockerfile (i usually use node:4-onbuild, but was trying something else):

```
FROM ubuntu
EXPOSE 3000
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install curl -y && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash - \
&& apt-get install -y nodejs && npm install --verbose
CMD npm start
```

A contrived example of the app with req-flash:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var redis = require('redis');
var session = require('express-session');
var redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var client = redis.createClient();
var flash = require('req-flash');

var PORT = '3000';
var app = express();
var redisSessionStore = new redisStore({host: 'redis-cache', port: 6379, client: client,ttl :  260});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'mySecret',
    store: redisSessionStore,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false
}));

app.use(flash({locals: 'flash'}));

app.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
    req.flash('testMessage', 'testing message');
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send(req.flash());
});

var server = http.createServer(app).listen(PORT);
```

Uppon visiting '/test':

```
Error: Sessions are required.
  at flash (/app/node_modules/req-flash/index.js:22:26)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
  at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
  at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
  at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
  at session (/app/node_modules/express-session/index.js:159:61)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
  at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
```

Redis container run command:

```
docker run -d --name redis-cache --net=iso_net_0 redis
```

App container run command:

```
docker run --name my-app-cont --net=iso_net_0 -p 3000:3000 myapp
```

Output from docker ps:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                     CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
9c14402243ee        myapp               "/bin/sh -c 'npm star"   About   a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   my-app-cont
57d79b87c3c4        redis               "docker-entrypoint.sh"   6 minutes ago        Up 6 minutes        6379/tcp                 redis-cache
```

docker network ls:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER
1e85a3458e9c        bridge              bridge              
9f6db289f96a        host                host                
7fdb5e3d4b83        iso_net_0           bridge              
1eb87fe46785        none                null
```

iso_net_0 is the bridged isolated network I created

docker network inspect iso_net_0:

```
[
{
    "Name": "iso_net_0",
    "Id": "7fdb5e3d4b83afe7fe53122c1c8486b0d00c092afcb8a72dd44d62c875187bd9",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": {},
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.18.0.1/16"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Containers": {
        "4588028f5a56f10258336b6dc4501e1c99b0145a4163473d76da4816062cb44c": {
            "Name": "my-app-cont",
            "EndpointID": "923ff4054a7c39cfc9c11ee3d49a810efadc504611205b6ce3db4c359190ded2",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "b5fcd1fa987e6a5fa4c3280c77a72f01ad23163fa56c5d3fd04ef75f15b67b6a": {
            "Name": "redis-cache",
            "EndpointID": "9cec94f3587048b9b6f8ac658cfa067f9684c2ddc48ec3d5531299b1e3dc71e9",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {},
    "Labels": {}
}
]
```

Comment: If you exec into the app container, can you connect to redis from inside of it? Can you update your answer with the docker run commands you use to start both containers, and docker-compose file, if using that, along with the `docker ps` output.

Comment: What is the `--net=iso_net_0` for in both the run commands? If you change to `--net=bridge` or remove the net flag all together (since bridge is default) does that work?

Comment: I'm guessing iso_net_0 is a custom network you setup. If changing to bridge works, then that means it is something with your network. Run these commands and post to your question `docker network ls` and `docker network inspect iso_net_0`

Comment: the iso_net_0 is the isolated bridge network I created. I intended to have both a redis and mongo container isolated from the default docker bridge network and only accessible to the app. If I remove that, expose the redis to the host and modify the redis host within app.js to localhost, the issue persists

Comment: OK, If you put things back the way you had them, and run the commands I gave in my last comment, let's see if that gives any info.

Comment: Thanks, everything looks fine. Ok one last thing. If you `docker exec -it my-app-cont bash` and then try connecting to redis using redis-cli or pinging the redis-cache container to test the network connection. If that works then we know networking is fine, and it might be your app, maybe a dns resolving issue (can test by using the 172.18.0.2 ip instead of redis-cache name) or just a config issue with the app, the error message doesn't give much, add some debug statements to find out more info.

Comment: yeah I tried connecting straight to the redis server (once exec'd) using redis-cli and the hostname and was fine. I'll try to get some more clear debug statements from req-flash

Comment: Ok, so it sounds that docker is configured fine, and not that. I don't know req-flash, so I can't help you there. Good luck

Comment: thanks for your time anyway :)